# Is it necessary to use an XADatasource if using multiple data sources in a single transaction?

Tags: transactions, datasource, wildfly

I have multiple DataSources that point to different schemas on the same MySQL database server. As I understand it, distributed transactions are commonly used when you have multiple webservers so you can rollback any changes if need be, but is it necessary to use XADataSources in this case though if it's the same database server and just different schemas?

When I tried to use the multiple data sources in a single transaction I got an error like this:

```
ARJUNA012140: Adding multiple last resources is disallowed. Trying to add     LastResourceRecord(XAOnePhaseResource)
```

I managed to fix this issue by adding this to standalone.xml:

```
 <system-properties>
      <property name="com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.allowMultipleLastResources" value="true"/>
 </system-properties>
```

But then I got this warning:

```
10:25:02,243 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Batch Thread - 3) ARJUNA012141: Multiple last resources have been added to the current transaction. This is transactionally unsafe and should not be relied upon. 
Current resource is LastResourceRecord(XAOnePhaseResource(LocalXAResourceImpl@7e0cda5c[connectionListener=da06ed8 connectionManager=76f8e0c5 warned=false currentXid=< formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffffc0a800de:5a5b164e:5878fd9f:10c, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffffc0a800de:5a5b164e:5878fd9f:10e, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:jboss/SomeDataJNDI> productName=MySQL productVersion=10.1.18-MariaDB jndiName=java:jboss/SomeDataJNDI]))
```

So now I'm wondering if I should be using multiple non-XA DataSources in one transaction. I'd like to avoid XADataSources if I don't need them.